# How to stop displaying error logs from the terminal in linux?

Tags: linux, logs, console

I am using Linux, there are some error logs related to some applications are over flooding one of my terminal.

They look like this:

```
20/01 15:54:29.894138[3319][65536] Unexpected exception during module loading
20/01 15:54:29.894459[3319][65536] %TFC-F-INIT_PB, Unexpected exception during module loading
Tue, 20 Jan 2015 15:55:00.0000000 [192linvm35:3355] (IT_CORE:7) F - Error in domain file file:///var/opt/temip/orbix/6X/orbix_temip.cfg - Failed to open file: /var/opt/temip/orbix/6X/orbix_temip.cfg : No such file or directory. Ensure that you have sourced your <domain_name>_env script, generated by the configuration tool ("itconfigure" command).

Alternatively, do either of the following: 
a) Pass the '-ORBdomain_name <domain_name>' and one of '-ORBconfig_dir <config_dir>' or -ORBconfig_domains_dir <config_domains_dir>' as parameters to the process.
b) Set the IT_DOMAIN_NAME environment variable to your <domain_name>, and set either IT_CONFIG_DIR to your <config_dir> or  IT_CONFIG_DOMAINS_DIR to your <config_domains_dir>.

In addition, you should also check your configuration file's read permissions.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These errors will be passed to your terminal from generally one of two places. Either

a) A running process from your existing shell is sending these errors to your screen

OR

b) Syslog is passing the errors to your own account or the root account if you are logged in as root. Or it is directing to a specific terminal.

The former can only be fixed by restarting the process and redirecting `STDERR` to `/dev/null` (assuming the errors are being sent to STDERR):

```
myprocess 2> /dev/null
```

It is most likely the latter if you are seeing this every time you log on, or especially if you are logged on as root (quite a few Linux releases configure syslog to send errors to the root user). Depending on your OS, the configuration of syslog (or rsyslog, or syslog-ng or a number of other syslogs) will have something along the lines of:

```
*.warn             root
```

inside their configuration. Either comment that line out, or set the severity level at which syslog redirects the output to root to a higher level (`*.err`, `*.crit`, `*.alert`, `*.emerg`). Note that setting the severity to a higher level means any other errors which would of been sent to your user/root will no longer be sent.

Syslog can also log to a specific terminal too:

```
*.warn             /dev/ttyS0
```

The same changes can be applied to this line as the line talked about above.

Comment: I am getting these error on one of my terminal not on all. So I think First one could be the reason. And how to get rid of it as I don't know which process is culprit?

Comment: First one is working for me, Thanks @Drav Sloan